# If centripetal acceleration varies with time then which velocity do I get on integrating the acceleration

Tags: centripetal-force

As the particle is in circular motion there is no radial component of velocity but which velocity is being given by integrating the time varying acceleration then?

Comment: If you're moving in a circle the only way for the centripetal acceleration to change is if your (tangential) speed changes. In that case your angular acceleration is not constant and you just integrate the angular acceleration to get the angular velocity and angular displacement. You'll need to clarify exactly what is happening in the situation you are asking about.

Comment: Maybe User161158 means by "time-varying acceleration" the ordinary direction-varying acceleration of uniform circular motion.

Answer (score 0):

From the definition of acceleration, we know that
 $$\vec a = \frac{d\vec v}{dt}$$
So, $$ \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \vec a\ dt = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} d\vec v$$
$$\Rightarrow \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \vec a\ dt  = \vec v_{t_2} - \vec v_{t_1}$$
$$\Rightarrow \int_{t_1}^{t_2} \vec a\ dt = \Delta \vec v$$

which is the change in the velocity vector in the time $t_1$ to $t_2$. In other words, if the particle is in uniform circular motion, you don't get a velocity when you integrate centripetal acceleration (which is the only acceleration here), you rather get the *change* in the velocity *vector*.

Also, if the particle is not executing uniform circular motion, then integrating the centripetal acceleration (which is just a component of total acceleration in this case) will *not give any meaningful result*.